# How did the Empire build the Death Star II so fast? Also, why would they build another after the first one failed so badly?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

According to Wookieepedia, only 3 years were in between the destruction of the first one and Episode 6. In episode 6, it was almost done and functional.[image]

Comment: Doesn't look almost done in that picture. I think there's something (maybe EU) that indicated the Death Star II was already under construction before Death Star first fired.